# How to get a pair of dependency relation between two words in a sentence using spacy?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, dependencies, spacy

I am using spacy to get the dependency relation, this works well. But I have a problem of getting a pair of token with a specific dependency relation (except for the `conj` relation).

When using the `.dep_`, I can get the dependency attribute of each seprate token.
However, I would like to a pair of token for a specific dependency relation.
For example, in the following code, I can get the shown result.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
sentence = 'The Marlins were stymied by Austin Gomber and the Rockies in their 4-3 loss'
doc = nlp(sentence)
for token in doc:
    print (token, token.dep_)
```

Current output:

```
The det
Marlins nsubjpass
were auxpass
stymied ROOT
by agent
Austin compound
Gomber pobj
and cc
the det
Rockies conj
in prep
their poss
4 nummod
- punct
3 prep
loss pobj
```

But what I **desire** to get is:
(please ignore the output style, I only want to get a pair of token with a specific dependency relation, e.g., here is `pobj`)

```
'Gomber' is a 'pobj' of 'by'
'Loss' is a 'pobj' of 'in'
```

In another word, I do not only want to get the result of **current output**, I also want to get **paired** token for each word.

For the `conj` dependency relation, I can get them simply by just using `token.conjuncts`, but for the rest of other dependency relations, such the `pobj`, `prep`, I have not found any method can be used directly in spacy.

Does anyone have a hint on getting this `pobj` relation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the head index. E.g.,

```
tok_l = doc.to_json()['tokens']
for t in tok_l:
  head = tok_l[t['head']]
  print(f"'{sentence[t['start']:t['end']]}' is {t['dep']} of '{sentence[head['start']:head['end']]}'")
```

Result:

```
'The' is det of 'Marlins'
'Marlins' is nsubjpass of 'stymied'
'were' is auxpass of 'stymied'
'stymied' is ROOT of 'stymied'
'by' is agent of 'stymied'
'Austin' is compound of 'Gomber'
'Gomber' is pobj of 'by'
'and' is cc of 'Gomber'
'the' is det of 'Rockies'
'Rockies' is conj of 'Gomber'
'in' is prep of 'stymied'
'their' is poss of 'loss'
'4' is nummod of 'loss'
'-' is punct of '3'
'3' is prep of '4'
'loss' is pobj of 'in'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this work very well. One more question, can you please explain a little bit more about the usage of 'doc.to_json()'? I have checked online, but there was not too much information about that, thanks again!

Comment: @Melina it simply creates a dict with various fields, see the [source](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/f4008bdb13e262c389e3d0c7017a634605f6e706/spacy/tokens/doc.pyx#L1431)